# Is there a way that we can reference the whole variable while in pattern matching of Elixir?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

There is an **as-pattern** in Haskell, which allows us referencing the whole variable while in pattern matching:

```
foo wholeList@(head:tail) = wholeList ++ head
```

The variable `wholeList` represents the original variable.

Assuming that `head` is `["Hello"]`, and `tail` is `["World"]`, then `wholeList` is `["Hello", "World"]`.

Using as-pattern, we can avoid constructing the variable again by concatenating `head` and `tail`.

Does such feature exist in Elixir?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Just use `=` in your pattern:

```
def foo(list = [h|t]), do: list ++ h
```